Integral of complex exponential with phase given by multiplication by a rational
I want to check that if $f \in L^1(\mathbb{T})$, $m$ is a positive integer, and $f_m(t) = f(mt)$ then
$$\widehat{f_m}(n) = \begin{cases}\hat{f}(n/m) &\text{ if } m \mid n, \\ 0 & \text{ if } m \nmid n.\end{cases}$$
I am able to check the case that $m$ divides $n$, but I'm stuck on the other case. I need to check that
$$\widehat{f_m}(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi m} \int_0^{2\pi m} f(\theta) e^{-i(n/m)\theta} \ d \theta = 0$$
whenever $m$ does not divide $n$.
I know that
$$\frac{1}{2\pi m} \int_0^{2\pi m} e^{-i(n/m)\theta} \ d \theta = \frac{m}{n}\left(\sin(2\pi n) + i \cos(2\pi n) - i\right) = 0,$$
but how should I deal with the case that $f$ is not just $1$?

You can approximate $f$ by a continuous periodic function and then by a trigonometric polynomial. Therefore it is enough to prove this when $f(\theta)=e^{ik\theta}$.Alternatively, you use integration by parts in the case of a smooth $f$.

@geetha290krm Can you explain how the integration by parts argument would work? If $f$ is smooth I can see how to show that the Fourier coefficients decay rapidly using IBP but I don’t see why they would be zero when m does not divide n
